# How to remove periods of time in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
       CODE    YEAR  MONTH DAY TMAX  TMIN   PP  BAD PERIOD 1 BAD PERIOD 2
9984   000130  1991    1    1  32.6  23.4  0.0     1991          1998
9985   000130  1991    1    2  31.2  22.4  0.0     NaN           NaN
9986   000130  1991    1    3  32.0   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
9987   000130  1991    1    4  32.2  23.0  0.0     NaN           NaN
9988   000130  1991    1    5  30.5  22.0  0.0     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...  ...
20118  000130  2018    9   30  31.8  21.2  NaN     NaN           NaN
30028  000132  1991    1    1  35.2   NaN  0.0     2005          2010
30029  000132  1991    1    2  34.6   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
30030  000132  1991    1    3  35.8   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
30031  000132  1991    1    4  34.8   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
50027  000132  2019    10   5  36.5   NaN  13.1    NaN           NaN
50028  000133  1991    1    1  36.2   NaN  0.0     1991          2010
50029  000133  1991    1    2  36.6   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
50030  000133  1991    1    3  36.8   NaN  5.0     NaN           NaN
50031  000133  1991    1    4  36.8   NaN  0.0     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
54456  000133  2019    10   5  36.5   NaN  12.1    NaN           NaN
```

I want to change the values ​​of the columns TMAX TMIN and PP to NaN, only of the periods specified in Bad Period 1 and Bad period 2 AND ONLY IN THEIR RESPECTIVE CODE. For example if I have Bad Period 1 equal to 1991 and Bad period 2 equal to 1998 I want all the values of TMAX, TMIN and PP that have code 000130 have NaN values since 1991 (bad period 1) to 1998 (bad period 2). I have 371 unique CODES in CODE column so i might use `df.groupby("CODE")`.

Expected result after the change:

```
       CODE    YEAR  MONTH DAY TMAX   TMIN   PP  BAD PERIOD 1 BAD PERIOD 2
9984   000130  1991    1    1  NaN    NaN   NaN     1991          1998
9985   000130  1991    1    2  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
9986   000130  1991    1    3  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
9987   000130  1991    1    4  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
9988   000130  1991    1    5  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...  ...
20118  000130  2018    9   30  31.8   21.2  NaN     NaN           NaN
30028  000132  1991    1    1  35.2   NaN   0.0     2005          2010
30029  000132  1991    1    2  34.6   NaN   0.0     NaN           NaN
30030  000132  1991    1    3  35.8   NaN   0.0     NaN           NaN
30031  000132  1991    1    4  34.8   NaN   0.0     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
50027  000132  2019    10   5  36.5   NaN  13.1     NaN           NaN
50028  000133  1991    1    1  NaN    NaN   NaN     1991          2010
50029  000133  1991    1    2  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
50030  000133  1991    1    3  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
50031  000133  1991    1    4  NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN           NaN
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
54456  000133  2019    10   5  36.5   NaN  12.1     NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can propagate the values in your bad columns with `ffill`, if the non nan values are always at the first row per group of CODE and your data is ordered per CODE. If not, with `groupby.transform` and `first`. Then use `mask` to replace by nan where the YEAR is between your two bad columns once filled with the wanted value.

```
df_ = df[['BAD_1', 'BAD_2']].ffill()
#or more flexible df_ = df.groupby("CODE")[['BAD_1', 'BAD_2']].transform('first')
cols = ['TMAX', 'TMIN', 'PP']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df['YEAR'].ge(df_['BAD_1']) 
                         & df['YEAR'].le(df_['BAD_2']))
print(df)
       CODE  YEAR  MONTH  DAY  TMAX  TMIN    PP   BAD_1   BAD_2
9984    130  1991      1    1   NaN   NaN   NaN  1991.0  1998.0
9985    130  1991      1    2   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
9986    130  1991      1    3   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
9987    130  1991      1    4   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
9988    130  1991      1    5   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
20118   130  2018      9   30  31.8  21.2   NaN     NaN     NaN
30028   132  1991      1    1  35.2   NaN   0.0  2005.0  2010.0
30029   132  1991      1    2  34.6   NaN   0.0     NaN     NaN
30030   132  1991      1    3  35.8   NaN   0.0     NaN     NaN
30031   132  1991      1    4  34.8   NaN   0.0     NaN     NaN
50027   132  2019     10    5  36.5   NaN  13.1     NaN     NaN
50028   133  1991      1    1   NaN   NaN   NaN  1991.0  2010.0
50029   133  1991      1    2   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
50030   133  1991      1    3   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
50031   133  1991      1    4   NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
54456   133  2019     10    5  36.5   NaN  12.1     NaN     NaN
```